# Запуск docker image jenkins-ом

Tags: docker, jenkins

Использую `jenkins` с `docker` для компиляции и тестирования своей программы, но возникла такая проблема: на этапе тестирования запущенная программа не может получить доступ к `Home direcotry` и сообщает:

```
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
```

Я думаю это из-за того, что в `image` задан `user`, а когда `jenkins` пытается запустить программу, он запускает его (контейнер) от своего имени, в результате чего не может получить доступ к директории внутри `image`. Но это только догадка.

Comment: 1. запись в `/etc/passwd` для этого пользователя внутри образа существует? 2. что указано в качестве домашнего каталога в этой записи? 3. кому принадлежит этот каталог?

Comment: 1. для какого этого? для jenkins или того, что задан в image? Если второе - то да. 2. в image указан /home/user - он же текущий рабочий каталог. 3. само собой принадлежит user

Comment: ввиду обще неразберихи, видимо, надо вернуться на шаг назад. какой процесс пишет сообщение, которое вы процитировали?

Comment: После коипиляции запускаю тесты, которые проваливаются, а перед этим пишут выше написанное сообщение и то, что (видимо из-за этого) невозможно инициализировать OpenGL ES. При этом плагин Xvfb установлен (как и сам xvfb) и запущен

Comment: ну вот с этого момента и начните: с выяснения, что за процесс вам это пишет. дальше выясните, в каком именно окружении он выполняется и от имени какого пользователя. а потом надо по второму кругу пройти три вопроса, приведённые в первом моём комментарии. // p.s. на всякий случай уточню, ввиду того, что вы всё время употребляете имя пользователя: судя по всему, у вас задействовано как минимум три изолированных (друг от друга) окружения, в каждом из которых свой собственнй набор пользователей, потому при выяснении надо манипулировать идентификатором пользователя, а не именем.